# Sort an array of objects in ruby using "sort"

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

How can I sort this array so all hashes with `optional = true` are last?

```
my_array = [
  { name: "foo", optional: true }, 
  { name: "pop" }, 
  { name: "boop", optional: true },
  { name: "pop", optional: false }
]
```

I tried this:

```
my_array.sort { |a,b| a['optional'] <=> b['optional'] }
```

But I get this error:

```
comparison of Hash with Hash failed
```

Error is surprising since doing a['optional'] would return a value of `true`, `false`, or `nil`.

**Note:**
I am aware of this solution `.sort_by { |a| (a['optional'] ? 1 : 0) }`. I would like to understand the `sort` method in particular.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Booleans are not ordinal data types - `true` is not larger or smaller than `false`, it's just not equal, so you can't use the `<=>` operator either. If you want to sort the array according to the optional property, you'd need some simple custom logic. E.g.:

```
my_array.sort { |a,b| a['optional'] == b['optional'] ? 0 : a['optional'] ? 1 : -1}
```

Answer (score 1):

For `sort` to work, you have to implement the block according to the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-sort):

> The block must implement a comparison between a and b, and return -1,
>   when a follows b, 0 when a and b are equivalent, or +1 if b follows a.

@Mureinik already showed you how to do that.

Personally I'd recommend using `sort_by`, since that's basically exactly the use case it was made for.